# cpio read error: Undefined error: 0 - XCode 8 installation

Tags: macos, installation, xcode

I've downloaded Xcode 8, tried to install it, and got this error message:

```
The operation couldn't be completed. cpio read error: Undefined error: 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

updating to OSX 10.11.6 solved the problem.